# using command line tools to extract and replace texts for translations

Tags: sed, command-line, grep

For an application, I have a language file in the way

```
first_identifier = English words
second_identifier = more English words
```

and need to translate it to further languages. In a first step I'm required to extract the right side of those texts resulting in a file like ...

```
English words
more English words
```

... How can I archive that? Using grep maybe?

Next I'd use a translation tool and receive something like

```
German words
more German words
```

that need to be inserted in the first file again (replace English words with Germans) now. I was thinking about using sed maybe, but I don't know how to use it for this purpose. Or, do you have other recommendations?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using standard PO files for this?

Comment: The reason is simple - I have an existing file in that format and want to add translations so I need to extract it in the desired way

Answer (score 0):

To do it as you describe would be:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmp=$(mktemp) || exit 1
trap 'rm -f "$tmp"; exit' 0

sed 's/[^ =]* = //' "${@:--}" > "$tmp" &&
tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' < "$tmp" |
awk '
    BEGIN { OFS = " = " }
    NR == FNR {
        ger[NR] = $0
        next
    }
    {
        sub(/ = .*/,"")
        print $0, ger[FNR]
    }
' - "$tmp"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
English words = ENGLISH WORDS
more English words = MORE ENGLISH WORDS
```

but you don't need a temp file for that:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sed 's/[^ =]* = //' "$@" |
tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' |
awk '
    BEGIN { OFS = " = " }
    NR == FNR {
        ger[NR] = $0
        next
    }
    {
        sub(/ = .*/,"")
        print $0, ger[FNR]
    }
' - "$@"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
first_identifier = ENGLISH WORDS
second_identifier = MORE ENGLISH WORDS
```

and I think this might be what you really want anyway so your translation tool can translate 1 line at a time instead of the whole input at once which might produce different results:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
    id="${line%% = *}"
    eng="${line#* = }"
    ger="$(tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' <<<"$eng")"
    printf '%s = %s\n' "$id" "$ger"
done < "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
first_identifier = ENGLISH WORDS
second_identifier = MORE ENGLISH WORDS
```

Just replace `tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' < "$tmp"` or `tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' <<<"$eng"` with the call to whatever translation tool you have in mind.

Comment: Well, thanks for the ideas Ed. 
Unfortunately, none of the provided scripts solve the mentioned issue.
`nils@pc:~$ cat testfile 
identifier_A=just a test
identifier_B=this is another test
identifier_C=a third one
nils@pc:~$ ./script.sh testfile 
identifier_A=just a test = IDENTIFIER_A=JUST A TEST
identifier_B=this is another test = IDENTIFIER_B=THIS IS ANOTHER TEST
identifier_C=a third one = IDENTIFIER_C=A THIRD ONE`

In fact, I expected something like the following instead:
`just a test
this is another test
a third one`

Do you have a hint, what I need to change?

Comment: Having said that - run my script against **the sample input you provided in your question** and if it doesn't produce the expected output from that then feel free to tell me about that,

Comment: That's what I tried to say and it does not produce the output as expected and requested in my question. In fact, I tried all three versions and on Ubuntu. The produced output for the original sample is "first_identifier = English words = FIRST_IDENTIFIER = ENGLISH WORDS"  ... which is wrong and the idea was to get the value of the right side of = only. So in case of the sample just "English words" and for the 2nd line "more English words" and so on ... the overall idea is to put the output to a translation service and assign new translation to the identifiers later on again.

Comment: As [I mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70849288/using-command-line-tools-to-extract-and-replace-texts-for-translations/70863881?noredirect=1#comment126049701_70863881), Please don't post sample input/output or code in comments as it can't be formatted. As you can see in my answer the scripts I provided produce the expected output (best I can tell - update your question if I'm wrong) from  the sample input you provided so if it doesn't work for you then either you copy/pasted it incorrectly or the input you're running it against now doesn't look like the input in your question.